# Extend a background into the margin

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

I have a `<div>` element that has a 10 pixel margin, as shown in the code below. My question is rather simple: how do I extend the background image into the margin? I tried using the CSS3 `background-clip` and `background-origin` sub-atributes, but they have no option for extending a background into the margin.

**CSS:**

```
#pagesidebar
{
    background-image:url('/Users/bagavatu/images/background.png');
    margin:10px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="pagesidebar">Hello</div>
```

I know I could append the `pagesidebar` div into a parent div, and simpyl apply the background-image there, but I would prefer a solution not requiring a new div.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Switch `margin: 10px` to `padding: 10px` and it should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

The background is relative to your div, not to margins, use paddings instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with a combination of [background-size](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) and [background-position](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp)